# Dynamically set entity context according to request url

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, routes

My web api 2  should provide two urls to clients: test.mydomain.com and production.mydomain.com
when a client access test, I want to instantiate test db context and production db for the production url.

Currently I can instantiate both manually: on each action inside the controller, I can check the url and determine if this, load this, if that load that.
However I would like to set the db automatically, without checking the request url on each action. I tried reading the request context in the controller constructor, but it is not there at that stage.

Action Filter? OnActionExecuting? But how could I instantiate it in the filter and use it in the controller actions? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like a good job for [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) / [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: This sounds much more complicated then it needs to be.  Is your database schema the same in your test environment and production environment (if they are different it defeats the purpose).  If so, simply use a Web.config for each environment which connects to the proper database.

Comment: Hi Justin, it is not a matter of different environment. It is the same application, same controller. The only thing is that I need to set the entity context at runtime according to the request url. I dont want to duplicate the whole code.

Comment: If you want to avoid any overengineering you could simply use a **factory** which would receive the current URL and provide the correct `DbContext`, then at the beginning of your request handling you would simply write: `using (MyContext context = ContextFactory.Get(currentUrl)){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Erik this can be solved reasonably easily using dependency injection.

1. Encapsulate creation of your context behind a factory that is responsible for creating the context based on a url parameter
2. Create a delegrating handler to examine the request and instantiate a new context based on the current url using the context factory
3. Cache the context in a caching object with a lifetime scoped to the current api request
4. Use the context caching object to retrieve the url specific context in all types that exist within the lifetime scope of the api request

Here's an example using AutoFac:

```
public interface IContextCache
{
    DbContext CurrentContext { get; set; }
}

// This will be wired as instance per api request
// and hence return the same context across the entire
// request from handler to controller
public class ContextCache : IContextCache
{
    public DbContext CurrentContext { get; set; }
}

public interface IContextFactory
{
    DbContext Create(Uri requestUri);
}

public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    public DbContext Create(Uri requestUri)
    {
        return CreateContextBasedOnUri(requestUri);
    }
}

// This is fired before the controller and creates and caches
// as per url context
public class ContextHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dependencyScope = request.GetDependencyScope();
        var contextFactory = (IContextFactory)dependencyScope.GetService(typeof(IContextFactory));       
        var contextCache = (IContextFache)dependencyScope.GetService(typeof(IContextCache));
        var context = contextFactory.Create(request.RequestUri);
        contextCache.CurrentContext = context;
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

// Uses the per api request scoped cache to retrieve the 
// correct context
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public MyController(IContextCache contextCache)
    {
        var context = contextCache.CurrentContext;
    }
}

// AutoFac wiring
// Perform boiler plate AutoFac registration for WebApi
// (See AutoFac documentation)

// Custom registrations
builder.RegisterType<ContextCache>()
    .As<IContextCache>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
builder.RegisterType<ContextFactoy>()
    .As<IContextFactory>()
    .InstancePerDependency();

// Handler registration
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ContextHandler());
}
```

Comment: why `contextFactory` is null in the context handler?